# Entity Framework - Create a copy of an object and remove an element in a copy's collection removes the element on both the original and the copy

Tags: entity-framework, collections, many-to-many, clone, dbcontext

I want to clone an object obtained from the db context using EF. Such object contains a collection that in turn contains another one.

For the copy or clone of the object, I have a method that creates a new instance, copies all the fields and finally marks the original one as EntityState.Unchaged.

```
Availability newAvailability = new Availability();
newAvailability = availabilityRepository.Copy(sourceAvailability, user);

newAvailability.RemoveTag(img, tagToRemove);
```

In the example, I have an availability which contains a set of images where each of them can have tags. What I want to do is to create a clone of the Availability object along with the images, then associate the tags to each image by using a join table.

In a next step, I want to remove a tag from one of the copied images, from the copied Availability.

The result is that the tag is being removed on both arrays.

What is weird, is that RemoveTag extension method doesn't use EF at all. It looks like this:

```
var filterExpression = new Func<Image, bool>(y => y.Url == img.Url));

var image = availability.Images.FirstOrDefault(filterExpression);
image.Tags.Remove(tag);
return availability;
```

Now, if I have an Availability like this (assume this the result of joining tables, an availability can have many images and an image can have many tags):

A = 1 ; Image = 1; Tag = 6

and then when I create its copy it looks like:

A = 2 ; Image = 2; Tag = 6

the result should be that the Tag 6 in Image 2 from the Availability gets removed and the source Availability is kept unchanged. But that's not what is happening.

Note: the Copy method is doing at some point

```
this.context.Entry(availability).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

What could I be doing wrong? How should I avoid EF from removing this child object from the source parent?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

Found the solution, although I'm not entirely sure what changes internally on doing this. I wrote

```
imgCopy.Tags = img.Tags;
```

but when I changed to

```
img.Tags.ToList().ForEach((_) =>
                {
                    imgCopy.Tags.Add(_);
                });
```

the problem was solved.

Comment: In the initial case, you were creating another reference pointing to the original object (img.Tags), so any changes you made using that refernce apply to the original object. In your changed code you created another, new object, so changes made to it were independent from the original object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.